# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rich.logging' in python

Tags: python, rich

I have **init**.py that includes this code and I get the error below the code:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import logging

from rich.logging import RichHandler

FORMAT = "%(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(
    format=FORMAT, datefmt="[%X] ", handlers=[RichHandler()], level=logging.INFO,
)

from . import ai
from . import cli
from . import clustering
from . import games
from . import poker
from . import terminal
from . import utils

__version__ = "1.0.0rc3"
```

when I run it I get this error:

```
>>> import poker_ai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\apps\1\poker_ai\poker_ai\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rich.logging import RichHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rich.logging'
```

This is the repo if you need:
https://github.com/fedden/poker_ai

Appreciate helping me to fix this error.

Comment: do you have `rich` installed? `from rich.logging import RichHandler` works for me. Try `import rich`

Comment: I tried that. but it didnt make any difference. I manually also did import rich  with no error but after I get this error again.

Comment: I can see logging.py under rich folder

Comment: when I trace the modules and try to run one by one from Python Idle GUI I get to a module called "colorama". I think when a module inside the module is not working the error is called on the parent file which is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the code has an error and needs to be fixed to

```
from rich.rich.logging import RichHandler
```

instead of

```
from rich.logging import RichHandler
```

this is how the python windows installer installs the code. Nevertheless this leads to another error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
```

which I need to handle.
Appreciate further help for 'coloroma'

Comment: I think that is the main issue, the modules are not correctly addressed in the files. Now next one missing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygments'"

Comment: Both codes are same... Try to reinstall **rich**.

Comment: you guys right, there was too many errors in that code. I gave up

Answer (score -1):

Long time since question asked but I happened upon the same and realized as well as solved most of these errors.

The majority of errors described seem to be missing packages, try installing rich, colorama etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).